# Cookie created in WebAPI response is never sent in subsequent client requests. Seeking example with round trip Server->Client->Server

Tags: asp.net, angular, google-chrome, cookies, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.Net Core 2 WepAPI controller.
Current version of Chrome(currently 64).
Angular 5 SPA.
Need to work on localhost.

This is controller method:

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet, Route("api/[controller]/test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append("testcookie", "testvalue", new CookieOptions
        {
            Path = "/",
            Domain = "localhost",
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(6),
            HttpOnly = false,
            Secure = false
        });

        return Ok("Test Ok.");
    }
}
```

And I don't think it matters, but this is my client code.

```
  private async test2() {
    const res = await this.http.get('http://localhost:59879/api/test/test').toPromise();
  }
```

When I look in Chrome Console -> Network Tab -> the request line -> Cookies Tab; I see my response cookie(s) but no request cookie.  I also do not see request cookie in `HttpContext.Request.Cookies` on subsequent requests.

How do I create *any kind of cookie*,

- that is created server side, and returned from controller method,
- and client/browser sends to server?

Assume server is on localhost:59879.

I have tried many iterations of setting the `Domain` to localhost, 127.0.0.1, false and excluding it.  Tried not specifying `CookieOptions` at all, no `Expires`, and various combinations of `HttpOnly` and `Secure` settings to no avail.

These are some resources I have tried.

- [HTTP Cookies in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies#cookies-in-web-api)
- [Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain)
- [Chrome localhost cookie not being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346919/chrome-localhost-cookie-not-being-set?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- Googled the following:  "net core 2 cookie -authentication"

**Update** - I see a recent [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49392275/angular-5-cookie-is-set-although-set-cookie-is-in-the-response-header) that *may* have the same cause of what I am experiencing.

Comment: So... [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/7369084) on the question [Chrome localhost cookie not being set](//stackoverflow.com/q/7346919) says that it won't work with localhost, and that you need a second-level domain name. Did you follow the instructions in that answer?

Comment: [@Mike McCaughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/mike-mccaughan), Yes, I specifically tried `http://127.0.0.1` for value of `Domain`..  In addition to trying `domain = Request.Host.ToString()`  and publishing to Azure with no luck.

Comment: What about "edit your hosts file to map a different URL with a TLD to the address 127.0.0.1 such as:

yoursite.tld   127.0.0.1"

Comment: Added `127.0.0.1 yoursite.com` to hosts file..  Veridied by pinging 'yoursite.com'.  Still only seeing Response Cookies set, but not Request Cookies.

Comment: [@Mike McCaughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/mike-mccaughan) - Did you just comment to make sure I tried the solutions that I stated I tried in my question, or do you have knowledge of setting a cookie server side with specified technologies and getting a result?

Comment: The workaround stated, using a full domain name, has worked in my experience. If that's not working for you, I suggest firing up IIS proper and try mapping the domain name there as well. You'll need to debug by attaching to the appropriate process.

Comment: Since there are other cookies being set and returned in the request by the client(related to Auth), and that that the implementation does not work even when published to Azure.  I feel safe to discard any solution related to installing IIS or editing the hosts file.  The existence of a solution  with-out is proven.  I have to assume the issue is related to how I create the cookie, with a very, very slight chance cause is client side.  For such a simple task, there has to be an existing SO, but I could not find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet, Route("api/[controller]/test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append("testcookie", "testvalue", new CookieOptions
        {
            Path = "/",
            Domain = "localhost",
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(6),
            HttpOnly = false,
            Secure = false
        });

        return Ok("Test Ok.");
    }
}
```

it will work if you accessing by browser. You trying access via ajax api, it won't work like that. If you analyze the code here:

```
Response.Cookies.Append("testcookie", "testvalue", new CookieOptions
{
    Path = "/",
    Domain = "localhost",
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(6),
    HttpOnly = false,
    Secure = false
});
```

this response is not access by browser, it access return ajax success.

See here [can-an-ajax-response-set-a-cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340797/can-an-ajax-response-set-a-cookie) thread.
Or solution in [mapping-header-cookie-string-to-cookiecollection-and-vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792638/mapping-header-cookie-string-to-cookiecollection-and-vice-versa).

That's not better approach access API and set-cookies via server, better it just do it on client side as discussion this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904685/ajax-call-to-net-and-sending-cookie-back).