# Angular 5 - Cookie is set although (Set-Cookie) is in the response header

Tags: php, angular, cross-domain, session-cookies

For an Angular 5 app, I have an auth service that does a HTTP POST which returns the session cookie (CORS) as shown below in the code below:

```
signIn(signInRequest: SignInRequest): Observable<SignInResponse> {
   let headers: Headers = new Headers();   
   headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');  
   return this.http
              .post("/login", {email:  signInRequest._email,password:signInRequest._password}, { headers: headers, withCredentials: true })
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);}
```

The response of the header contains the set-cookie as shown below:

[image]

and the request header is the following:

[image]

I know that the browser should be setting the cookie response. Why is it not doing it?

Comment: I have a similar question I am struggling with and about to post a bounty on.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352181/cookie-created-in-webapi-response-is-never-sent-in-subsequent-client-requests-s

Comment: maybe related to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers ?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo the cookie is being returned in the response header so not sure what to expose here ?

Comment: @ttugates same as you, i have been struggling with this the past two days.

Comment: Its my first time to ever work with cookies, so before your post, I assumed I was missing something obvious..  Just added 50pt Bounty to my SO.

Comment: @HamzaAdli the fact that you can see them in dev tools doesnt mean that scripts can access to them AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

Your frontend is hosted on `localhost:4200` and your backend is hosted on `api.safra.me`. By default, your browser won't send the cookies along the request unless you use the [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) in the login request as you already did, **and all of the subsequent requests**.